# Can I still use `manage.py test` after switching to django-pytest?

Tags: python, django, testing

It'd be good to keep using the convention of using `manage.py test` to run tests instead of introducing a new command that isn't standard to Django projects.

Writing tests that py.test can consume is wonderfully concise. Can you get the best of both worlds and wire up Django's `manage.py test` to run those tests?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like there's an out-of-the-box way to do this, so I [added a PR to django-pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/pull/225) to support this.

Add the following to `settings.py`:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'pytest_django.runner.PyTestRunner'
```

And then you can run

```
manage.py test
```

Comment: to me it raises error

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom TEST_RUNNER but you need add it to your code.

Check the FAQ of pytest-django: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-manage-py-test-with-pytest-django

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32619218)

Comment: Good catch, but the text is very long, I add the commit link: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/0be78e9781682dec745be628ec5fc86ef5f8a3e1/docs/faq.rst#how-can-i-use-managepy-test-with-pytest-django.

I this link doesn't work, you shouldn't use this module hahahah