# How to call pytest-django from python manage.py test?

Tags: django, django-admin, pytest, pytest-django, django-management-command

I have made my custom management command called pytest_wrp

So when I call

```sh
python manage.py test
```

This bit of code is called:

```py
class Command(test.Command):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options) # this calls the python manage.py test
        self.stdout.write("My code starts from here.")
        management.call_command(pytest_wrp.Command(), '--pact-files="{argument}"'.format(argument=path_to_file), '--pact-provider-name="MyService"', verbosity=0)
```

The `pytest_wrp` basically has this code in it:

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Runs tests with Pytest"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("args", nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        pytest.main(list(args)) # This doesn't accept the pact args, even if you specify a "--" separator
```

But this calls `pytest` not `pytest-django`
Hence the extra arguments that I am passing don't get recognized and pytest can't start the test suite.

I wanna pass the extra arguments for some of the test cases.
If there is some way to call pytest-django directly and pass the extra arguments in code that would be optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my solution here:
[Can I still use `manage.py test` after switching to django-pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419615/can-i-still-use-manage-py-test-after-switching-to-django-pytest)
and for full and comprehensive documentation you need to see [this](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-manage-py-test-with-pytest-django). To put it simply, you need to override the `config/test.py` or `config.py` depending how your app was setup

```
TEST_RUNNER = "your_project.your_app.runner"
```

And your `runner.py` would look something like this

```
class PytestTestRunner(object):
    """Runs pytest to discover and run tests."""

    def __init__(self, verbosity=1, failfast=False, keepdb=False, **kwargs):
        self.verbosity = verbosity
        self.failfast = failfast
        self.keepdb = keepdb

    def run_tests(self, test_labels):
        """Run pytest and return the exitcode.

        It translates some of Django's test command option to pytest's.
        """
        import pytest

        argv = []
        if self.verbosity == 0:
            argv.append('--quiet')
        if self.verbosity == 2:
            argv.append('--verbose')
        if self.verbosity == 3:
            argv.append('-vv')
        if self.failfast:
            argv.append('--exitfirst')
        if self.keepdb:
            argv.append('--reuse-db')

        # NOTE: You don't need to quote the argument value here, they do some weird string pattern matching internally
        argv.append('--pact-files={argument}'.format(argument=path_to_file)) 
        argv.append('--pact-provider-name=MyService')
        argv.extend(test_labels)
        return pytest.main(argv)
```

Please make sure you have `pytest-django` package

```
pip install pytest-django
```

Comment: for me its doesn't work TEST_RUNNER = "your_project.your_app.runner". Instead, TEST_RUNNER = "your_app.runner.PytestTestRunner" worked

Comment: What's `path_to_file`?